# I can not connect MongoDB using .env file. When i connect directly using id and password then working fine:

Tags: mongodb

const uri=mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.x3xvq.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 1):

install the dotenv module and run the config function before using any env variables
example:
import {config} from 'dotenv'

config();

console.log(process.env.db_url);